# What is the best way to access specific tensors in a shuffled queue?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, video-processing

I am processing video data in python using tensorflow and want to run a loss calculation using temporal information using the current frame and the ones before and after it.  After I've read in the images they are shuffled using tf.train.shuffle_batch as is necessary for the training.  However later I want to access the frame before and after the current one, is there a way to access the specific tensor for those frame by maintaining (for want of a better phrase) a pointer to the tensors corresponding to those frames?

At the moment I read in all frames 3 times, once for itself and once each for the frame before and after so they can be shuffled together but this seems inefficient to be reading in and storing the same frame info multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no other way than the one you already implemented. Shuffling uses a limited buffer where items are stored and randomly sampled from. If you shuffle individual frames, you don't even have the guarantee the three frames are in the queue at the same time, let alone the possibility to know where they end up in the queue.